# Copy text from WPF DataGrid to Clipboard to Excel

Tags: wpf, clipboard

I have WPF DataGrid (VS2010 C#). I copied the data from DataGrid to Clipboard and write it to an Excel file. Below is my code.

```
dataGrid1.SelectAllCells();
dataGrid1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dataGrid1);
dataGrid1.UnselectAllCells();
string path1 = "C:\\test.xls";
string result1 = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
Clipboard.Clear();
System.IO.StreamWriter file1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path1);
file1.WriteLine(result1);
file1.Close();
```

Everything works out OK except when I open the excel file it gives me two warning:

> "The file you are trying to open
>   'test.xls' is in a different format
>   than specified by the file extension.
>   Verify that the file is not corrupted
>   and is from a trusted source before
>   opening the file. Do you want to open
>   the file now?"
>
> "Excel has detected that 'test.xls' is
>   a SYLK file, but cannot load it."

But after I click through it, it still open the excel file OK and data are formated as it supposed to be. But I can't find how to get rid of the two warnings before the excel file is open.

Comment: I think It's becouse the file hasn't got the correct extension.

Comment: Excel has an extension of ".xls"... isn't it?

Comment: Excel Spreadsheets are .xls. But Excel can open other file formats as well, such as a comma separated value file (.csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem like yours has already been described here : [generating/opening CSV from console - file is in wrong format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286511/generating-opening-csv-from-console-file-is-in-wrong-format-error).
Does it helps to solve yours ?

Edit : Here is the Microsoft KB related => http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626

Answer (score 4):

You need to use csv as extension. Xls is the Excel file extension. 
So

```
string path1 = "C:\\test.csv";
```

should work.