# Change csv delimiter for Clipobard.GetData()

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, export-to-csv

I try to save a datagrid as csv via copy datagrid to clipboard acording to this post: 
[Copy text from WPF DataGrid to Clipboard to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015438/copy-text-from-wpf-datagrid-to-clipboard-to-excel)

The export works, but the column delimiter is **","** but I use a german region setting with **";"** delimiter character. The hole text is in one column:(

Can I change the DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue delimiter?

Thank you and have a nice day

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved to problem by save the DataTable instead the DataGrid. The DataTableExtensions class in the link below works very well.

[c# datatable to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can change the delimiter. If you don't find a way, you can always do this:

```
string result1 = ((string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)).Replace(";",",");
```

Comment: hi, thanks. But by this solution the problem is my decimal mark is ","

Comment: If you have commas in the file and want to use semi-colon, use Replace(",",";"). If you have semi-colon in file and want to use commas, use Replace(";",","). All you're asking the compiler to do is switch one character for another. REPLACE("{CURRENT_STRING}","{DESIRED_STRIGR}"); Cheers!

Comment: You dont understand me. i have comma as field delimeter AND as decimal mark. regards

Comment: Sorry - yes, I'm trying to allow for language. Is there ever a comma between two numbers in your data that is a delimiter? In other words, could we say that any comma between two numbers is a decimal indicator, not a separator?

Comment: Can you share a few line of your CSV? Perhaps we can parse most if not all of it with predictive algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you can't change it.

I would agree with what someone already said in [your link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015438/copy-text-from-wpf-datagrid-to-clipboard-to-excel) - you shouldn't be saving csv data to an xls file. When you open a .csv file with excel, it will ask you what delimiter you want to use before you import it.

If you want to change your delimiter before saving, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25308707/6614344).
Make sure to also take a look at the link in that answer - you'd need to use the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO namespace.

**However**, if you still decide to save as .xls, be careful - you might change your delimiter to ';' before saving, but people whose excel expects ',' as a delimiter will have the same problem you have now.

Comment: hi, thanks for the replay. i dont try so safe the file as a xlsx. I save it as .csv but my excel (2007) dont ask my about the delimeter. i open the csv with a double click not over the open dialog.